# Partition expiry countdown for date/time field based partition

Tags: google-bigquery

As of May 2021, Google Big Query documentation does not clearly mention when the countdown for partition expiry for time/date field partitioned table start? Is the *date/time of the partition itself* is the start of the partition expiry countdown or does the expiry countdown start when the partition is ***created***?

For example, if a table like following is created

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_id.dataset_name.table_name`
(
    dateTime    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    , trainName STRING
    , fleet     STRING
    , customer  STRING
)
PARTITION BY DATE(dateTime)
OPTIONS (
    partition_expiration_days = 3
)
```

**So, if the table is created on say 5th of the month but while inserting the data, if the data for 1st of that month (for field `dateTime`) is inserted, will that data be expired already upon insertion? Or will it expire on 9th of the same month?**

For ingestion based partitioning this confusion does not arise as the ingestion timestamp itself is a partition timestamp.

References:

- [Create a time-unit column-partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_a_time-unit_column-partitioned_table)
- [Updating default partition expiration times](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#partition-expiration)
- [Use the expiration settings to remove unneeded tables and partitions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage#use_the_expiration_settings_to_remove_unneeded_tables_and_partitions)

Answer (score 0):

That data will expire on insertion. Date/time of the partition itself is the start of the partition expiry countdown. So, data for the 1st of the month will not be present in the table.